# Can I add another condition into the Angular.js synchronization

Tags: angularjs, protractor

Protractor does wait for Angular.js process to finish before continuing with the execution flow. It does this in every step (after every click() call, etc.).

I'm testing an application which has a lot of "loaders" that for some reason are not caught by this synchronization and I'm getting a lot of errors.

I can manually put a wait after each instruction but it would be good to execute this wait after each instruction.

Is there a way to add another condition to the protractor synchronization mechanism?

Comment: Have you tried using implicit wait, which executes after each and every protractor instruction? You can write one in your `onPrepare()` function of conf.js file - `browser.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(35000);`. If you get wait timeout error then increase your `defaultTimeoutInterval: 80000` so that protractor waits for a longer period before it timeouts.

Comment: I understand your point. But what I think I need is not a normal timeout, but a wait() until a graphic loader dissapears. I already have a function waitUntilLoaderDissapears(), but I need that function to be executed after every protractor instruction. I guess a workaround would be to put that function in afterEach(), but I think that is only executed after every it() function.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so this is a bit hackerish, but I found this way. Protractor uses `waitForAngular()` after each webdriver command. https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/f034e010156a85cf1826b95eb7f41f50ef5a1791/lib/protractor.js#L319

You can alter that function in for example `onPrepare:`

```
browser.waitForAngular = function(opt_description) {
        var description = opt_description ? ' - ' + opt_description : '';
        var self = this;
        waitUntilLoaderDissapears();
        if (this.ignoreSynchronization) {
            return self.driver.controlFlow().execute(function () {
                return true;
            }, 'Ignore Synchronization Protractor.waitForAngular()');
        }
    };
```